# Why the class Remark is not inheriting the Average class value?

Tags: java, inheritance

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Average {
    int math, programming, oop, total;
    public void setGrade(int math, int programming, int oop) {
        this.math = math;
        this.programming = programming;
        this.oop = oop;
        this.total = (math + programming + oop) / 3;
    }
    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }
}

class Remark extends Average {
    void remark() {
        int totalMark = super.getTotal();
        if(totalMark >= 75) {
            System.out.println("Pass");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Fail");
        }
    }
}

class Course extends Average {
    void decideCourse() {
        int total = super.getTotal();
        System.out.println("Average: " + total);
        if(total >= 91 && total <= 100) {
            System.out.print("Course Offered: \nBSE, BEED, BSAT");
        }
        else if(total >= 81 && total <= 90) {
            System.out.print("Course Offered: \nBSIT, BSCS, BSBA");
        }
        else if(total >= 75 && total <= 80) {
            System.out.print("Course Offered: \nBSITECH, DAT, BSHRM");
        }
        else if(total < 75) {
            System.out.print("Average did!");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int math, programming, oop;
        System.out.print("Enter Grade: ");
        System.out.print("\nMath: ");
        math = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Programming: ");
        programming = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Object-Oriented Programming: ");
        oop = sc.nextInt();
        Course c1 = new Course();
        Remark r1 = new Remark();
        c1.setGrade(math, programming, oop);
        r1.remark();
        c1.decideCourse();
    }
}
```

This problem is related to inheritance. A student need to be graded on the average marks.
In this code class Remark is not extending Average class, when i try to get the total from Average class, its not inheriting.. whats the error here... other parts are working fine

Comment: You never call `setGrade` on `Remark` `r1` so its `total` as well as its `math`, `programming`, and `oop` fields are all zero.

Comment: Quick comment about inheritance. Your modelling `Course extends Average` doesn't look correct. This means that `Course` is an `Average` - Not sure if it makes sense in your domain.

Answer (score 1):

Each Remark (including `r1`) and each Course (including `c1`) will have its own copy of all of the fields you define in Average. It is not the case that there is one shared copy of Average; there is one for each instance of Average, and each instance of Remark and Course contains space for all of Average's fields.

No matter what values you enter, `r1.remark()` will always print "Fail" because you're setting the values in `c1` and not `r1`. Though `r1` will inherit the definition of `getTotal` from Average, you haven't set the values, so they'll all have the default value of 0 and consequently `getTotal` will return 0.

(Side note: Though it works from a technical standpoint, you might not see cases later where classes like Remark and Course extend a class like Average: You are representing that if some other part of your program needed an Average, you could pass in a Remark or a Course, and that doesn't make as much sense as if (for instance) you had Course, Assignment, and Exam all extend GradableItem. You'll see that principle referred to as the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).)